# Unexpected bracket - PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error, brackets

Here is some PHP mixed with HTML, I apologize that it's quite messy.

```
  <div class="media"><?php echo ($inf['post_url']) ?><img src="<?php echo($inf['photos'][0]['alt_sizes'][0][url]); ?>" /></div>
  {block:Caption}<?php if (array_key_exists('caption', $inf))?><div class="copy"><?php Echo ($inf['caption']);?></div><?php }; ?>
  <?php }; ?>
```

The second line produces this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 1708
```

I do not see anything wrong with the brackets. What is producing this error?

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but you're missing a semi after echo ($inf['post_url'])

Comment: Maybe if your code was a little more organized with whitespace and indentation, you would be able to see the problem very clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd format your code properly so it'd actually be readable, the superfluous bracket (and missing opening bracket) would be easy to spot:

```
    <div class="media">
        <?php echo ($inf['post_url']) ?>
        <img src="<?php echo($inf['photos'][0]['alt_sizes'][0][url]); ?>" />
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
    <?php if (array_key_exists('caption', $inf))?>
        <div class="copy">
            <?php Echo ($inf['caption']);?>
        </div>
    <?php }; ?>
<?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It greatly helps if you indent your code correctly.

```
    <div class="media">
        <?php echo ($inf['post_url']) ?>
        <img src="<?php echo($inf['photos'][0]['alt_sizes'][0][url]); ?>" />
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
    <?php if (array_key_exists('caption', $inf)) ?>
        <div class="copy">
        <?php Echo ($inf['caption']);?>
        </div>
    <?php }; ?>
<?php }; ?>
```

Very basic, the closing brackets do not have corresponding opening brackets.

Some more stylistic advice: echo is a PHP construct, so you don't need to call it like a function, that is `echo something` is equivalent to `echo(something)` but the former is preferred. Also, it pays to be consistent with the capitalisation of reserved words, i.e. if you're using lowercase, **always** use lowercase for reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra bracket at the end as well as some superfluous semicolons, and "echo" was capitalized. Give this a shot:

```
<div class="media">
   <?php echo ($inf['post_url']); ?>
   <img src="<?php echo($inf['photos'][0]['alt_sizes'][0][url]); ?>" />
</div>
   {block:Caption}
   <?php if (array_key_exists('caption', $inf)) {?>
     <div class="copy">
     <?php echo ($inf['caption']);?>
     </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you boil off all the HTML, lines 2 and 3 come out to this:

```
if (array_key_exists('caption', $inf)) Echo ($inf['caption']); };  };
```

You don't need either of those closing right curly braces.

Comment: Don't need semicolons after braces either.

Comment: Nor does echo need to be capitalized -- I was merely reproducing the existing PHP code sans markup =)